# Is there a way i can get select a range before a formula gets applied to a specific cell?

Tags: excel, vba

For e.g i'm currently using an array formula "={INDEX(A1:A28,MATCH(MAX(COUNTIF(A1:A28,A1:A28)),COUNTIF(A1:A28,A1:A28),0))}" that tells me which text/string appears the maximum no. of times within the specified range i.e. A1:A28.

I'm trying to find out if using VBA or any other way, to get a pop up box that asks to select the range of cells before applying the formula?.

Thanks

Neel

Comment: Can you post what you've tried so far?  One way is via the InputBox, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7643541/how-to-generate-the-range-selection-dialog-box-using-vba-in-excel, but your situation may be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

First click on the cell in which the formula should be deposited and then run:

```
Sub Neel()
    Dim s As String, s2 As String, Z As String, addy As String
    Dim where As Range
    Z = "Z"
    s = "=INDEX(Z,MATCH(MAX(COUNTIF(Z,Z)),COUNTIF(Z,Z),0))"
    Set where = ActiveCell
    addy = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Pick Range", Type:=8).Address(0, 0)
    s2 = Replace(s, Z, addy)
    where.FormulaArray = s2
End Sub
```

Comment: Many Thanks Gary's Student!, that worked like a charm!!